# why the third option is better than regex?

Tags: javascript, performance

I think regex is pretty fast and the third option is confusing. What do you think?

http://jqfundamentals.com/book/ch09s12.html

```
// old way
if (type == 'foo' || type == 'bar') { ... }

// better
if (/^(foo|bar)$/.test(type)) { ... }

// object literal lookup 
if (({ foo : 1, bar : 1 })[type]) { ... }
```

Comment: Barring your doing this several hundred thousand times in the course of something the user is waiting for, it doesn't remotely matter (and I'm not buying that the other options are better cross-implementation, either). Go for readability and maintainability (the first option).

Comment: Does she really mean that third one is the best? Seems like she just tells the option.

Answer (score 6):

I'll humbly disagree with Rebecca Murphey and vote for simplicity, for the first option.

*I think regex is pretty fast*
Machine code is even faster, but we don't use it.

*the third option is confusing*
It's only confusing if you're unfamiliar with the trick. (And for people not used to seeing regex to compare two strings, second option will be even more confusing.)

Answer (score 5):

I just made a rudimentary benchmark and I'm honestly not sure how she got those results...
http://jsbin.com/uzuxi4/2/edit

Regex seems to scale the best, but the first is by far the fastest on all modern browsers. The last is excruciatingly slow. I understand the complexity theory between the three, but in practice, it doesn't seem that she's correct.

Let alone the fact that the first also has the best readability, it also seems to be the fastest. I even nested loops to take advantage of any browser caching of literal tables or constants (to no avail).

---

**Edit:**
It appears that when an object is explicitly created, she is indeed correct, however: http://jsbin.com/uzuxi4/4/edit

```
function __hash() {
  ...

  var type = 'bar';
  var testobj = { foo : 1, bar : 1 };
  var c = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (testobj[type]) {
      for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
          if (testobj[type]) { c++; }
      }
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

We see that once the object has an internal reference, the seek time drops to about 500 ms which is probably the plateau. Object key lookup may be the best for **larger** data-sets, but in practice I don't really see it as a viable option for every-day use.

Comment: She's ignoring the cost of what she's doing -- a [] access to an object is not cached in any modern engine, and of course you have to allocate that object (and then pay gc cost later).

Answer (score 2):

1. The first option involves
   potentially two string compares.
2. The second option involves a parse each time.
3. The third option does a simple hash of the string and then a hash table look
   up, which is the most efficient in this case, in terms of the amount of work that needs to be done.

The third option also scales better than the other two as more alternative strings are added, because the first two are O(n) and the third is O(1) in the average case.

If we want to talk about which option is prettier / more maintainable, that's a whole separate conversation.

Comment: The third option is O(n) also: you have to create hash first. (unless you want cache it manually, of course)

Comment: Of course, it also involves a completely unnecessary memory allocation and still requires the string comparisons for the true case (the hashes *can* be sufficient for the false case, but not the true). It's also difficult for maintainers to read and any performance benefit almost certainly implementation-dependent and not worth the trouble in any but edge cases.

Comment: Yes, but presumably the hash is created once and then reused with a good javascript interpreter, because the values are constant. I do agree with T.J. Crowder on it being more difficult to read, though.

Comment: @Michael: So, not the one in the most popular browser on the planet, then.

Comment: @Michael: We're all hoping, yeah. :-)

Comment: most efficient? i created this test and string is the fastest... http://jsperf.com/string-vs-regex/3

Answer (score 1):

The first case should really be done with `===` to avoid any type coercions, but depending on the number of alternatives you need to check it can become `O(N)`, however depending on your code most JS engines will be able to a simple pointer check for the comparison.

In the second case you use a RegExp, and while RegExps are very fast, they tend to be slower for simple equality decisions than more direct equality comparisons.  Simple string comparisons like yours are likely to be a pointer compare in a modern JS engine, but if you use a regexp the regexp *must* read every character.

The third case is more tricky -- if you do have a lot of values to check it may be faster, especially if you cache the object rather than repeatedly recreating it as it will simply be a hash lookup -- the exact performance of the lookup depends on the engine though.

I suspect a switch statement would beat the object literal case though.

Out of curiosity I made a test (which you can see [here](http://nerget.com/jstests/performance/ComparisonTest.html)), the fastest approach (in a webkit nightly at least) seems to be a switch statement, followed by if, followed by the object, with regexp's last.

Comment: +1, I honestly don't understand how she can call case 2 or 3 "best practices" and I really hope we won't start seeing everyone doing simple comparisons with `regexp`

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to weigh in here and remind everyone that this is an open-source book with contributions from many people! The section being discussed, indeed, is based on content provided by a community member. If you have suggestions for improving the section, by all means, please open an issue on the repository, or better, fork the repo and send me a pull request :)

That said, I have just set up a jsPerf test (http://jsperf.com/string-tests), and at least in Chrome, the results are the opposite of what the book says. I've opened an issue on the book, and will try to deal with this in the near future.

Finally, two things:

- I want to echo what another commenter said: perf optimizations are fun to talk about, and while there are some that really do matter, many don't. It's important to keep perspective on how much -- or little -- of a difference stuff like this makes.
- I also want to echo the commenter who said, essentially, that readability is in the eyes of the beholder. Something confusing to one person may be perfectly clear to another. I do believe we should strive for readability, but I think there's a happy medium. Reading code that was a bit perplexing to me at first opened my eyes to a lot of great techniques; I'd have hated if it had been written so the complete newb that I was at  the time could understand it.

Comment: i created this test before i saw your post and i'm actually shocked at the results. http://jsperf.com/string-vs-regex/3

Answer (score 0):

The object literal lookup is optimized with a hash lookup which only requires one logical check instead of n.  In a longer list you also won't have to repeat "type == " a zillion times.

Comment: but you have to allocate and create the object

Comment: Yes, but with a well implemented JS interpreter it doesn't have to be created multiple times.  I'm not saying that it is necessarily implemented well.

Comment: You can't not allocate the object every time, as the object can escape.  For example:

Comment: erk, hitting enter in comments submits why?

Comment: Object.prototype.__defineGetter__("wibble", function(){this.x = old.x+1; old=this;}); then if ({....}[someUnknownValue]) { ... } can escape and you have to create a new object.  A lot of the slowness in JS is caused by the _possibility_ of someone doing something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity and readability the first will win every time. It might not be as fast, but who cares unless it is in a heavily run loop.

Good compilers should optimize things like this away.

Comment: what are they optimising away?  This is javascript is surprisingly difficult to optimise things out.

Comment: When you are comparing two items you could argue the readability is better in the first one but if you have 4 or more it is going to start to fall onto more than one line and readability becomes an issue.

Comment: @olliej: Lots of things are difficult to optimize in dynamic languages like JavaScript, but not `if (type == 'foo' || type == 'bar')` :-)

Comment: @T. J. Crowder: what are you going to optimise out? You have to do the checks (note i am assuming that strings are interned so you can typically get away with a pointer compare)

Comment: I took a graduate level CS course where I optimized the heck out of a C++ program. My optimized program faired worse than what the compiler could do with "standard" code. Everyone in the class was the same way. Algorithm design is far more important then agonising over a single line or two. C++ is not Javascript, but the more vanilla your code is the easier for machine and human to work with.